# copy files from IIs6.0 server to client machine without showing file dialog window on click of button in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, python, ruby

File.VBS file should be copied from IIS6.0(File.VBS file will be deployed in IIS along the ASP.NET3.5 application) server to Client “TEMP” folder with out opening the file download dialog box.

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot do that. It would be a huge security hole. Why would you need to do something like this?

Comment: @Cheeso:  Sounds like an answer to me.  "No you can't and don't even try" is a reasonable answer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment by Cheeso,

### this is not possible!

This would constitute **a very dangerous security hole**!

Although brief on this topic, the [**RFC 2616**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) is none the less explicit on this point, in particular with regards to the User Agent's (read the "Web Browser") duties in that regard.

```
The receiving user agent SHOULD NOT respect any directory path information 
present in the filename-parm parameter, which is the only parameter believed
to apply to HTTP implementations at this time. The filename SHOULD be treated
as a terminal component only.

If this header is used in a response with the application/octet- stream 
content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent should not display
the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.
```